# Understanding the Soundcloud cocoa wrapper api

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, json, soundcloud

I'm somewhat familiar with Cocoa, Objective-C and iPhone Development using Xcode. I'm starting to incorporate this [cocoa-wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper) in my iPhone project, but it's a steep learning curve for me. What topics should I be reading on (or buying books for) to understand how to use this wrapper in an efficient manner?

Here are some links to documentation that I find a bit intimidating:

- [Usage](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Usage.md)
- [Sharing](https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper/blob/master/Sharing.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

[SoundCloud API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs) or the [Discussion Group](http://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi) for more direct help.